# Pode reabrir esta pergunta que pede uma informação de programação que o AP não sabe?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Alguém achar que não deve reabrir favor explicar. Pra mim parece um fechamento *non-sense*, mas dou o benefício da dúvida.

[Arrays em loops](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204907/101)

Comment: 3 pessoas votaram como "não está em português". Eu estou realmente confuso.

Comment: Aliás, meu voto é que pode reabrir sim.

Comment: Tinha uma frase em inglês quando elas votaram, mas os votos ficam lá, talvez elas não tivessem votado em outro motivo. O que eu acho estranho são os outros dois votos. Me **parece** que no fundo tem um voto de alguém que pensa em fechar perguntas deste tipo, o que eu discordo, e outro que a pessoa não analisou bem, foi no que já estava no gatilho, os outros 3 deveriam ter sido expirados se o mecanismo fosse melhor. A pergunta é fraquinha, claro.

Comment: Ah sim, agora que eu percebi que estava parte em inglês mesmo.

Comment: @bigown mesmo com a frase em inglês na versão original da pergunta, o voto para fechar por conta de idioma mostra que quem votou para fechar não se deu ao trabalho de ler a pergunta.

Comment: @Renan concordo.

Comment: @bigown se o primeiro que dizes te referes a mim acertaste ;)

Comment: Eu ia reabrir mesmo a não ser que alguém desse um motivo muito bom. Me pareceu um equivoco. Nem sempre faço isso, mas tem caso que quero ver a posição das pessoas pra me balizar para outros casos, e ver se o pessoal para de agir como se fosse usuário do SOen.

Comment: @bigown mas até gostei da resposta :D

Answer (score 5):

Não fui um dos fechadores, mas concordo com alguns pontos do motivo fora de escopo. A ênfase é minha:

> Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. **Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro**.

Não acho que a pergunta deva ser fechada - afinal, ela não se encaixa perfeitamente na descrição acima. Por isso votei para reabrir. Sou a favor de outra atitude, que é a do voto negativo. Afinal, o *alt-text* do voto negativo diz:

> Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil.

Agora, para aqueles que votaram para fechar a pergunta por não estar em Português, o meu voto é que voltem à escola. Sintam-se gratos pelo voto de fechamento não relacionar o motivo à pessoa, porque esse foi motivo de vergonha.

Comment: Renan, não estava em inglês no começo, ainda que fosse só uma frase. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/204907/4

Comment: Eu vi. Mas achei que a primeira frase em português era suficiente. Afinal a gente vê muitas perguntas aqui com mensagens de erro em inglês...

Comment: @Renan como se pode ver concordo com a sua ênfase ;)

Comment: +1 Me parece uma pergunta "dever de casa", mas do tipo muito mal elaborada. Não vejo como pode ser útil no futuro.